# Bilingual WP site: How to achieve different URL sturcture rule based on its language?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

A wordpress website with bilingual setup, with three languages:

- English ("primary language") : "en"
- Traditional Chinese : "zh-hant"
- Simplified Chinese : "zh-hans"

The bilingual setup is currently achieved with the polylang plugin.

I would like to have different URL structure based on the post's language.

For English,

```
example.com/blog/%category%/%postname%/
```

And the above permalink sturcture is my current set up in the WP permalink setting page.
(custom structure, /blog/%category%/%postname%/)

But for non-English blog post URL, I would like to use post id instead of postname:

```
example.com/zh-hant/blog/%category%/%post_id%
```

The polylang plugin does not allow me to have different permalink setting per language, so I think I need a custom function solution to this.

Comment: Please follow the plugins guides. URL Modification is answer. https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/setting-up-a-wordpress-multilingual-site-with-polylang/settings/

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, but the plugin itself doesn't allow you to do different setting per language. I am looking for a custom function solution to this question.

Comment: `%post_title%` - I think you meant `%postname%`? And what is your current permalink structure? Does it have "blog" - `blog/%category%/%postname%` - could you please add the structure into your post?

Comment: Hi Sally, you are right, I made a typo when I posted the question. My current permalink setting is (1) Custom Structure, (2) /blog/%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Thanks for editing the post, but that `example.com/blog/zh-hant/`, I believe, should have been `example.com/zh-hant/blog/`.. :) Anyway, see my answer.

Comment: yes you are right, it's example.com/<language>/blog....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Add the rewrite rules for the `<language>/blog/%category%/%post_id%` structure.

   I used the [`post_rewrite_rules` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_rewrite_rules/) to add the rewrite rules, but for generating the rewrite rules, I used [`WP_Rewrite::generate_rewrite_rules()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/generate_rewrite_rule/) the same way WordPress core used it to generate the rewrite rules for the default permalink structure (that you set via the Permalink Settings page).

   ```php
   add_filter( 'post_rewrite_rules', 'my_post_rewrite_rules' );
   function my_post_rewrite_rules( $post_rewrite ) {
       global $wp_rewrite;

       // Generate the rewrite rules for example.com/<language>/blog/<category slug or path>/<post ID>/
       $post_rewrite2 = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules(
           '^zh-han[st]/blog/%category%/%post_id%',
           EP_PERMALINK
       );

       // Combine the rules, with the new ones at the top.
       return array_merge( $post_rewrite2, $post_rewrite );
   }
   ```
2. The above step ensures that the URLs do not result in a 404 error, and now, we need to filter the permalink URL generated via [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) so that the URL uses the correct structure.

   Normally, one would use the `post_link` hook to replace the rewrite *tag* (`%post_id%` in your case), but `%post_id%` is a core [rewrite/structure tag](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#structure-tags) in WordPress, so we can simply use the [`pre_post_link` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_link/) to set the structure to `/blog/%category%/%post_id%/` *if* the post language (slug) is `zh-hans` or `zh-hant`. I.e. We just need to set the structure and the tag will be replaced by WordPress.

   Note: `pll_get_post_language()` is a Polylang function; see [here](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/) for further details.

   ```php
   add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'my_pre_post_link', 10, 3 );
   function my_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
       if ( ! $leavename && is_object( $post ) &&
           preg_match( '#^zh-han[st]$#', pll_get_post_language( $post->ID ) )
       ) {
           $permalink = '/blog/%category%/%post_id%/';
       }

       return $permalink;
   }
   ```
3. Be sure to flush the rewrite rules after you've added the above functions to your theme/plugin — just visit the Permalink Settings page without having to click on the Save Changes button.

Additionally, the RegEx pattern `^zh-han[st]` will match both `zh-hans` and `zh-hant`. You can [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/UqGzbv/1).

Comment: Hi Sally, thank you for the answer. It works like a charm. Only thing I notice is that I have yoast SEO plugin installed, and when I create a new post in Chinese, upon clicking on the save button, it trigger yoast plugin to create URL redirection.  Seems like when I save the post, it created chinese character URL permalink first and immediate the custom function takes effect... and since there was a URL changed, it triggered yoast plugin to created an URL redirection.

Comment: Try the updated code in step 2, but if the issue still happens, then I'm afraid there's nothing else I could do..

Comment: Tried the update code, the site still create chinese URL first before the custom code. Overall, it still works for me, I just have to delete the redirection from yoast plugin, thank you for your help Sally. PS. I still need help with the other question... kindly help me out when you have time. Thank you again!

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by "create URL redirection"? Can you try disabling all other plugins? Did you use Gutenberg or the old/classic editor? If you deactivate Yoast, does the issue persist? Can you *show* (like via a short video) the steps you took when "saving" the post?

Comment: If you mean the original permalink with the slug in the URL (e.g. `example.com/zh-hant/blog/uncategorized-zh-hant/你好，世界！`), then yes, I didn't include the code which disables that original URL.

Comment: when yoast detect a URL change of a post, in order to avoid 404 page not found, it will automatically create a redirection link.

For example, if I create a post with url "example.com/blog/hello-world" and then I update its permalink to "example.com/blog/hello-hello", then yoast will automatically create a "blog/hello-world" ---> "blog/hello-hello" redirection

Comment: so I think what actually happened was that when I use the custom function code to create different permalink rule for non-english posts, when I click saved, WP use the URL rules FIRST and created the link accordingly, and then right after that, the custom function code update the permalink update, which trigger the yoast seo plugin to create a 301 redirection. if there is a way to hook the function replace the WP permalink setting, it will work perfectly

Comment: or maybe a if lang != "en" ..then use the custom function to setup the permalink instead ...

Comment: [If this is what you meant](https://yoast.com/features/redirect-manager/), then although Yoast SEO may not be at fault, I can't help you any further, unless maybe if I see the Yoast SEO premium's source. And I'm not saying my code is perfect, but it worked for what it's for - setting a custom permalink structure for certain posts only - right? So maybe try asking in Yoast forums and ask if there's any way to disable/filter the redirect URLs via a hook.

Comment: Yes your code works for my purpose, thank you for your help. the yoast redirection things doesn't hurt much. I was just curious that, can't we tell WP not to generate the post url twice. I thought we can tell WP "if lang for the post is not english, use our custom code for setting up the permalink, do not generate url from the default setting at all

Comment: That's what my code is doing, except for this: "do not generate url from the default setting at all", and I mentioned Yoast source code because if we could find out what WordPress hook/function they use to generate the redirect URL, then we can do that last part in your previous comment. But you can try replacing the `preg_match( '#^zh-han[st]$#', pll_get_post_language( $post->ID ) )` with `'en' !== pll_get_post_language( $post->ID )`.